# Fields that are not saved in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I was reading the `ProgressBar` source code and I reached `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    // Force our ancestor class to save its state
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);

    ss.progress = mProgress;
    ss.secondaryProgress = mSecondaryProgress;

    return ss;
}
```

As can be seen, only the `progress` and `secondaryProgress` fields are saved, so what happens to all the other fields the user can set, such as `max`? Why aren't they saved as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user cannot set `android:max` directly via the widget.

Generally speaking, `onSaveInstanceState()` tends to worry about user-mutable state, such as whether or not a `CompoundButton` is checked, or state that is highly likely to vary during runtime as a result of user actions, such as the progress state of a `ProgressBar`.

You, of course, are welcome to subclass or fork `ProgressBar`, using an `onSaveInstanceState()` that saves other data that you want, or have your activity or fragment save the data in their implementations of `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: But I can always put a button that when pressed, will call `setMax`, so is it my activity's responsibility to save `max` in this case?

Comment: @user940016: "so is it my activity's responsibility to save max in this case?" -- yes. I have also edited the first sentence of my answer for better clarity. My apologies for any confusion.